# Can I evenly size my grid rows to fit visible content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I would like  to show a css grid with equal row height filling the visible height. The grid items can be more than fit.
Here an image how it should work. The row height should be equal and always fill the container of the grid. With flex in horizontal I would know, but I think with flex this is not possible.

[image: grid]

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  background: white;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.row{
  font-size: 3rem;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    row1
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row2
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row3
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row4
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row5
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row6
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row7
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row1
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row8
  </div>
</div>
```

The rows should always fill the visible height. The count can be fix, say 4.

Comment: You would need to specify the number of rows.

Comment: That is ok, but then how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `grid-template-rows: repeat(9, auto);`. Of course, the number specifies the number of rows, if these increase in your html, then you will need to change this value in your css.Hope this helps, if you have any doubts take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows

In case you want to center the content / text of the lines just add this to your `.row` class `display: flex;` `align-items: center;`

**Working snippet**

```css
.container {
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  background: white;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, auto);

}

.row{
  font-size: 3rem;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    row1
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row2
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row3
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row4
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row5
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row6
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row7
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row8
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row9
  </div>
</div>
```

**Snippet not working (for demonstration purposes)**

```css
.container {
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  background: white;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 100px);

}

.row{
  font-size: 3rem;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    row1
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row2
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row3
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row4
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row5
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row6
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row7
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row8
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row9
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but thats not the result I need. The count of rows should fit the VISIBLE height of the container. If only the rows would be on a page you could say the 4 rows should be visible in height 100vh

Comment: But the rows are adapting perfectly to the visible height of the container. I set the container height to 1000px as an example, you can put to 100vh or delete, the rows will always fit the height of your container. Or do you mean something else? Maybe I'm not understanding ...